# Removing ADLDS in Windows Server

Tags: ad-lds

I installed active directory Light directory service accidentally as i already has ADDS installed after installation all services are stopped in Server Manager and unable to do refresh i want to remove it please help me out from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't delete it from the Programs and Features, use cmd:

```
ADAMuninstall /i: instancename /answer:d:\dirpath\filename
```

where `instancename` is the name of AD LDS instance you want to remove, and `d:\dirpath\filename` is the location and name of the file you can type in the credentials of an AD LDS admin for this specified instance. File must contain:

```
Administrator=yourdomain\youradministrator
AdministratorPassword=youradminpassword
```

Comment: please explain the thing d:\dirpath\filename ?

Comment: i got the instance name running the command but i am unable to understand the dir /filename

Comment: An unattended removal of AD LDS can only be performed under the security context of the AD LDS administrator. If you are not currently logged on as the AD LDS administrator, you can specifythe AD LDS administrator credentials through a text answer file.

Answer (score 2):

It should be able to be removed without interfering with AD.

To uninstall:
c:\windows\adam\adamuninstall.exe /i:instanceName

To list instances:
dsdbutil “list instances” quit

Comment: on running or clicking adamuninstall.exe its just open a command prompt and still not removing AD LDS

Comment: You have to specify the instance name. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers describe how to remove an AD LDS *instance* from a server. However, none of them address removing the AD LDS *role* (Windows Feature) from a server. In the case of the question, when the AD LDS role is installed but not configured, there are no AD LDS instances to remove, so the adamuninstall.exe will not work. Using dsdbutil to list instances will show your Active Directory (NTDS) instance, which you DO NOT want to remove.

To remove the AD LDS role when no instances are configured, open an elevated powershell window and enter `remove-windowsfeature adlds`. This will remove the role from the Roles & Features view in Control Panel and Server Manager. You can verify this worked by running `get-windowsfeature adlds`. The removal does not require a server reboot.